# What are you supposed to do with the original field that you translate with django-modeltranslation?

Tags: python, django, django-modeltranslation

I specify in settings.py the languages the fields of the models should be available in:

```
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('zh-cn', gettext('Simplified Chinese')),
    ('zh-tw', gettext('Traditional Chinese')),
)
```

But when I apply the migrations, this will mean that apart from the original field, it will create these additional three fields. If the original field was "name", I will now have "name", "name_en", "name_zh_cn", and "name_zh_tw".

What is one supposed to do with the original field? Ignore it? Delete it? Should I just not put English in LANGUAGES and treat the original one as the English translation?

When I looked for solutions on their Github page, someone said that you can just set the default to the language you want, and not include it in your TRANSLATIONMODEL_LANGUAGES, https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation/issues/488#issuecomment-457427502 but this isn't true (at least for the most recent release of translationmodel), because it will give you a `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: MODELTRANSLATION_DEFAULT_LANGUAGE not in LANGUAGES setting.` error.

Comment: You're not translating the *model fields*, are you?! Just their labels in the UI. Where exactly would this generate anything like `name_en`?

Comment: @deceze I am translating the model fields... I thought that's what django-modeltranslation is for?

Comment: Sorry, I ignored the [tag:django-modeltranslation] entirely.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve not having the additional english field with the following settings:

```
gettext = lambda s: s
LANGUAGES = (
    ('en', gettext('English')),
    ('zh-cn', gettext('Simplified Chinese')),
    ('zh-tw', gettext('Traditional Chinese')),
)
MODELTRANSLATION_LANGUAGES = ('zh-cn', 'zh-tw')
```

This isn't necessarily a best practice since you are expected to use the original value: https://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#rules